# Firebase Cloud Messaging notification from Java instead of Firebase Console

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to Firebase and I am running into errors such as mismatch sender id and Authentication Error with HTTP status 401 when my Java application tries to send a notification/message using the client's Firebase token. Note that using Firebase Console, I am able to send the message to the client.

For the client app, I did the following:

1. Cloned Firebase `messaging` quickstart app from here -- https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging -- which is already setup with Firebase dependencies and such. Loaded the cloned app in `Android Studio`.
2. Using Firebase Console, created a new project called `My Notification Client` and added an app using `com.google.firebase.quickstart.fcm` as the package name of the Android app.
3. Downloaded `google-services.json` file for the Android app added to the newly created project and copied it to the `messaging/app/` folder and sync'd with Grade files from within `Android Studio`.
4. Created an emulator and ran the app from within `Android Studio`. When the app got loaded in the emulator, clicked the `Log Token` button to capture the client's Firebase token in the `Android Monitor` tab in `Android Studio`.
5. Using Firebase Console, selected the newly created project `My Notification Client`, clicked the `Notifications` link from the left pane, and sent a notification to the device by pasting the Firebase token captured in the previous step.

This worked great! The next step was to to use a separate simple Java application (which would eventually become a notification server) to send the notification to the client instead of using Firebase Console.

To accomplish this, I followed the steps outlined here -- https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup#prerequisites. Specifically, these are the steps that I performed:

1. Created a new project called `My Notification Server` in Firebase Console.
2. Using `Settings > Permissions` in Firebase Console, created a new service account and downloaded the `serviceAccountCredentials.json` file.
3. Created a new maven project in Eclipse and added the following dependencies in pom.xml:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gcm</groupId>
      <artifactId>gcm-server</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
      <artifactId>firebase-server-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

1. Then, I extended `com.google.android.gcm.sender.Sender` to create `FCMSender` and override protected method `getConnection(String url)` to use the new FCM endpoint as shown below:

   ```
   class FCMSender extends Sender {

       public FCMSender(String key) {
           super(key);
       }

       @Override
       protected HttpURLConnection getConnection(String url) throws IOException {
           String fcmUrl = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
           return (HttpURLConnection) new URL(fcmUrl).openConnection();
       }
   }
   ```
2. The `main()` method of my Java application looks like this:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       // Obtain serverKey from Project Settings -> Cloud Messaging tab
       // for "My Notification Client" project in Firebase Console.
       String serverKey = <get_server_key_from_firebase_console>;
       Thread t = new Thread() {
           public void run(){ 
               try {
                   Sender sender = new FCMSender(serverKey);
                   Message message = new Message.Builder()
                                     .collapseKey("message")
                                     .timeToLive(3)
                                     .delayWhileIdle(true)
                                     .addData("message", "Notification from Java application");
                                     .build();  

                   // Use the same token(or registration id) that was earlier
                   // used to send the message to the client directly from
                   // Firebase Console's Notification tab.
                   Result result = sender.send(message,
               "APA91bFfIFjSCcSiJ111rbmkpnMkZY-Ej4RCpdBZFZN_mYgfHwFlx-M1UXS5FqDBcN8x1efrS2md8L9K_E9N21qB-PIHUqQwmF4p7Y3U-86nCGH7KNkZNjjz_P_qjcTR0TOrwXMh33vp",
                       1);
                   System.out.println("Result: " + result.toString());
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           };
           t.start;
           try {
               t.join();
           }
           catch (InterruptedException iex) {
               iex.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   ```

When I run the Java application, I get `MismatchSenderId` error. I tried troubleshooting using `curl` as shown below but got the same error:

```
$ skey=<obtained_from_project_settings_cloud_messaging_tab_in_firebase_console>
$ curl -X POST --header "Authorization: key=$skey" \
  --Header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
  -d "{\"to\":\"APA91bFfIFjSCcSiJ111rbmkpnMkZY-Ej4RCpdBZFZN_mYgfHwFlx-M1UXS5FqDBcN8x1efrS2md8L9K_E9N21qB-PIHUqQwmF4p7Y3U-86nCGH7KNkZNjjz_P_qjcTR0TOrwXMh33vp\",\"data\":{\"message\":\"Yellow\"}}"

{"multicast_id":7391851081942579857,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}
```

Instead of using the `Server Key` listed on `Project Settings > Cloud Messaging` tab for `My Notification Server` project in Firebase Console, I tried using the `Project Number` but that caused `InvalidRequestException: HTTP Status Code: 401`.

Firebase documentation of the error codes says this about `MismatchSenderId`:

> Mismatched Sender 200 + `error:MismatchSenderId`
>   A registration token is tied to a certain group of senders. When a client app registers for FCM, it must specify which senders are allowed to send messages. You should use one of those sender IDs when sending messages to the client app. If you switch to a different sender, the existing registration tokens won't work.

I could not figure out where/how in Firebase Console one can configure the Android app(which was aded to the `My Notification Client` project) to be able to receive messages.

Any help on this, would be appreciated!

Comment: You can check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51172021/3073945

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was running into the same issue. The problem was in the line:

```
String serverKey = <get_server_key_from_firebase_console>;
```

This value should come from the Android app project; in this case it would be "My Notification Client" and not "My Notification Server".

Comment: You are right! I didn't need the "My Notification Server" project at all. Using the server-key from the "My Notification Client", I was able to make it work.

Comment: Most of the time the Authorization key we are using could be wrong.
Check http://dev.tapjoy.com/faq/how-to-find-sender-id-and-api-key-for-gcm/    to see you are using the correct key or not . I also got confused while selecting API key for firebase 
We have to use SENDER ID - API KEY pair in Cloud messaging tab under firebase setting.
i.e. 
Go to firebase App--> Go to app setting --> Cloud Messaging
there you can find Sender Id <==> API key 
and this API key you can use to send FCM.

Answer (score 10):

I too have recently started using Firebase, with no prior experience in Google Cloud Messaging.  AFAIK, there's no server side SDK for Firebase Cloud Messaging, currently.

To send notifications/messages from your App Server to your Mobile Client, you need to implement your own HTTP and/or XMPP methods.  See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

My testing code, using HTTP:

```
public CompletableFuture<String> fcmTest1() {
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref
    String host = "fcm.googleapis.com";
    String requestURI = "/fcm/send";
    String CLIENT_TOKEN = "ASK_YOUR_MOBILE_CLIENT_DEV"; // https://developers.google.com/instance-id/

    CompletableFuture<String> fut = new CompletableFuture<>();
    JsonObject body = new JsonObject();
    // JsonArray registration_ids = new JsonArray();
    // body.put("registration_ids", registration_ids);
    body.put("to", CLIENT_TOKEN);
    body.put("priority", "high");
    // body.put("dry_run", true);

    JsonObject notification = new JsonObject();
    notification.put("body", "body string here");
    notification.put("title", "title string here");
    // notification.put("icon", "myicon");

    JsonObject data = new JsonObject();
    data.put("key1", "value1");
    data.put("key2", "value2");

    body.put("notification", notification);
    body.put("data", data);

    HttpClientRequest hcr = httpsClient.post(443, host, requestURI).handler(response -> {
        response.bodyHandler(buffer -> {
            logger.debug("FcmTest1 rcvd: {}, {}", response.statusCode(), buffer.toString());
            if (response.statusCode() == 200) {
                fut.complete(buffer.toString());
            } else {
                fut.completeExceptionally(new RuntimeException(buffer.toString()));
            }
        });
    });
    hcr.putHeader("Authorization", "key=" + Utils.FIREBASE_SERVER_KEY)
        .putHeader("content-type", "application/json").end(body.encode());
    return fut;
}
```

note: http client and json were provided by vertx (http://vertx.io/), but hopefully the code shows what's going on clear enough so you can use whatever you wish.

Comment: There is a server side sdk firebase-server-sdk

Comment: @Hamedz Not for use towards FCM from what I could find.

Comment: firebase-server-sdk is deprecated in favor for firebase-admin-sdk, and quoting Google documentation on the latter: "The Firebase Admin Java SDK does not currently have an FCM API. If you want to send messages from a non-Node.js server, you should use the HTTP or XMPP APIs as explained in About Firebase Cloud Messaging Server". FCM being Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: @aes How to get the registrationToken by sending the custom field information to firebase ?

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an FCMHelper Class, that works fine and is simple to use.

See here https://github.com/MOSDEV82/fcmhelper

Comment: Thank you!! It worked for me. Able to send FCM from Web-Services to Android Devices.

Comment: thank you for this, saved some time, simple and elegant, to the point and works well.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to send FCM notification from my java EE application and I found [this](https://github.com/Raudius/Pushraven) very helpful. Might save someone some time.

...The github repo is a library interface for Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) API (NB// I am not the author). So I followed instructions in the readme: added the jar file as a dependency to my project and could just invoke the library methods with respective parameters.

e.g. `Pushraven.setKey(my_key);` to set your server key and

```java
Notification raven = new Notification();
raven.title("MyTitle")
     .text("Hello World!")
     .color("#ff0000")
     .to(client_key);
```

to build a notification. The instructions from the repo are pretty much clear and helpful.

Comment: Please add more information to your answer, at least a description of the link and how it helps to solve the issue...

Comment: Ok. The github repo is a library interface for Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) API (NB// I am not the author). So I followed instructions in the readme: added the jar file as a dependency to my project and could just invoke the library methods with respective parameters. e.g. `Pushraven.setKey(my_key);` to set your server key and `Notification raven = new Notification();
raven.title("MyTitle")
  .text("Hello World!")
  .color("#ff0000")
  .to(client_key);` to build a notification. The instructions from the repo are pretty much clear and helpful.

Comment: That's better :-) I suggest you move that comment into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

On:

> `// Obtain serverKey from Project Settings -> Cloud Messaging tab
>       // for "My Notification Server" project in Firebase Console.
>       String serverKey = <get_server_key_from_firebase_console>;`

You must obtain the key for your android app.

And thank you, I was struggling to build a service to send/receive notifications for the app. Saw your question, tried to get it right, and used to build mine. Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exacly same problem, and even used your code as a test to check if there was something wrong with mine. It turns out that both of our codes were right. The problem is exacly as described on Firebase docs:

"Mismatched Sender   200 + error:MismatchSenderId    A registration token is
tied to a certain group of senders. When a client app registers for FCM, it
must specify which senders are allowed to send messages. You should use one
of those sender IDs when sending messages to the client app. If you switch
to a different sender, the existing registration tokens won't work."

Problem is, that´s not that clear (at least wasn´t for me).
So here's what you need: On your Android application, you'll need to receive the Firebase key for the device . It is not the same you used to have for the Google Cloud Message, and hence there´s the problem.

Just create this class on your Android project:

public class NotificacaoRegistro extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    static private String TAG = "NOTIFICACAOREGISTRO";

```
public NotificacaoRegistro(){
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
}
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
    // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.

}
```

}

Don't forget to make the necessary changes on your AndroidManifest

```
  <service
            android:name=".notificacoes.NotificacaoRegistro">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
  </service>
```

If you just need the code (for debugging, for example) you can just call on your MainActivity, in your OnCreate method

String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

But it´s better, ofc if you take care of that properly.

That way you'll get the correct key for that device. Then on your Java application code

```
   Result result = sender.send(message,
            <PUT THE VALUE OF THE REFRESHED TOKEN HERE>,
                    1);
```

and you are all set :)

Hope this helps, and sorry about the long delay :)

cheers

Answer (score 0):

#### Use this sending push notifications from java.

Spring Framework

Compared to other projects there are just 3 simple classes with minimal dependencies.

https://github.com/AndreiD/testingpushnotifications

Remember to replace the SERVER_API_KEY and the Client_Token.

*[image: PS. Written by me]*